# Grab Text of the onclick event when the text is changed on hover with elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to grab the text of what is clicked 
Upon finding a jquery flyout menu, I can see that the css is on hover changing its color so i did add in a

I created a fiddle with the html,css and javascript that shows the code i'm working with

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/rcfgt0kj/

I know that I am in the right spot as i added in this code to debug with a click , then "this"   but what I don't know is how to grab the text of the hover   "this" simply grabs way too much.

```
$(".flexdropdownmenu").click(function () {
    console.log('click');
    console.log(this);

});
```

**HTML** (it is in the fiddle)

```
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="text" data-flexmenu="flexmenu1" value="dropdown">
    <!--<a href="#" data-flexmenu="flexmenu1">Chose Status</a>-->
```

```
    <!--HTML for Flex Drop Down Menu 1-->
    <ul id="flexmenu1" class="flexdropdownmenu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">CCO</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4a</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item Folder 5a</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1a</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item Folder 5.2a</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.1a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.2a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.3a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.4a</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: If you rollover "Sub Item 5.2.1a"  then YES , i want to grab that text , so console.log write it out or whatever as i will end up putting it into a variable etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code

```
$(".flexdropdownmenu").click(function (e) {

    console.log($(e.target).text());

})
```

;